# How to define parameters to report server model

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created one model (smdl) in my report server. (using Business Intelligence Development Studio in VS 2008)
The model has a Customer entity which as fields such as "Customer name", "City", "Country", and rest other statistical data.

I want to design a report based on this model.
I want to give a report parameter on "City" filed. The problem is that, if I directly put City as a parameter by dropdown list in the report, it displays all cities but getting duplicated for obvious reasons.
So I think the best place is to define somewhere in report model, rather than report.

How can I define report parameter in report model.

Comment: why not create a second dataset which will return distinct values and then use it as the source of your parameter dropdownlist?

Comment: you mean to say, creating a second dataset in the report itself, rather than creating in report model?